# How to determine if Directory Browsing is turned on in IIS in the site, app, and folder level in powershell

Tags: powershell, iis

I'm asked, for the first time, to provide a powershell query to determine if Directory Browsing is turned on in IIS.  What I have found out is that Directory Browsing could be enabled not only in the site level, but in the app level or web service level.

This is a little advanced for me.
Does anyone know how this works?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use powershell IIS Snapin, following example will get the value for default website:

```
Get-WebConfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/directoryBrowse -name enabled -PSPath 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site'
ItemXPath                   : /system.webServer/directoryBrowse
IsInheritedFromDefaultValue : False
IsProtected                 : False
Name                        : enabled
TypeName                    : System.Boolean
Schema                      : Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationAttributeSchema
Value                       : False
IsExtended                  : False
```

Comment: thanks.  where in this is directory browsing? and is there a way to just pull that part of the data?  appreciate it.

Comment: look at value, yes you can select : | select value

Comment: Thank you very much.  This helps a lot.

Comment: This answer does not cover the other pieces of the question.  It only displays the information for the website, not folders or applications within, nor does it display the information for the server itself, although that was not originally asked for.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first solution, because it is more simple, even though I dislike to use appcmd.exe in a PowerShell script, because it´s not seems "elegant" to me.

It´s necessary to create a file with a list of servers to be checked: serverList.txt. Just write the hostname, one by line.

This script check config of all apps, because it´s more common to change configuration of these. But this verification it´s not complete, because you can change configuration of a common directory too. I´ll fix this in the next version.

The result is just a information about if the DirectoryBrowse feature is enabled or not. This feature, if enabled, could be a security issue. So it could be a good idea to implement a function to disable this feature.

```
<#
: IIS Security ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
: Verifica desvios de seguranca nos site/app
:   - DirectoryBrowse
:
#>
$serverList = Get-Content -Path C:\Middleware\serverList.txt

foreach ($server in $serverList){
    $appList = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list app}
    foreach($app in $appList){
        $siteApp = ($app -split '"')[1]
        
        # SECTION:directoryBrowse
        $appConfig = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list config "$siteApp" -SECTION:directoryBrowse}
        $result = (($appConfig | Select-String -Pattern 'directoryBrowse enabled="false"') -split '"')[1]
        if ($result -eq "false"){
            Write-Output "$($server): $($siteApp) - Directory Browsing desabilitado"
        }
        else {
            Write-Output "$($server): $($siteApp) - Directory Browsing HABILITADO <<<<<"
        }
    }
}
```

The result...

```
PS C:\Middleware> C:\Middleware\IIS_Security_v1.ps1
WIN-UNDBQ49VK01: Default Web Site/ - Directory Browsing desabilitado
WIN-UNDBQ49VK01: SorveteriaBruna/ - Directory Browsing desabilitado
WIN-UNDBQ49VK01: SorveteriaBruna/Contrato - Directory Browsing desabilitado
WIN-UNDBQ49VK01: AcougueLindoBoi/ - Directory Browsing desabilitado
WIN-UNDBQ49VK01: AcougueLindoBoi/Contrato - Directory Browsing desabilitado
WIN-UNDBQ49VK01: FunerariaStones/ - Directory Browsing desabilitado
WIN-UNDBQ49VK01: FunerariaStones/Contrato - Directory Browsing desabilitado
WIN-UNDBQ49VK01: FtpHome/ - Directory Browsing desabilitado

PS C:\Middleware>
```